# How to avoid this redundancy and close non used File classes?

Tags: java, file, io

**Introduction**

I am doing some homework where I am tasked for doing a program that manages files using the path (absolute). Read file info, write/read them, etc.

**My attempt**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package fichersapren;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 *
 * @author alumneM
 */
public class FitxersApren {

    public static String working_path = "";
    public static Calendar cal;


    /**
     * Get username from system
     */
    public static void obtenirNomUsuari()
    {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.name"));
    }
    /**
     * Create file
     * 
     * @param path
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void crearFicher(String path) throws IOException
    {
        File cf = new File(path);
        cf.createNewFile();
    }
    /**
     * Create Directory
     * 
     * @param path 
     */
    public static void crearDirectori(String path)
    {     
        File cd = new File(path);
        cd.mkdir();
    }
    /**
     * Get file info
     * 
     * @param path 
     */
    public static void mostrarInfoFitcher(String path)
    {
        File infoF = new File(path);
        System.out.println("Nombre fichero: " + infoF.getName());
        System.out.println("Permisos: ");
        System.out.println(" - Escritura: " + infoF.canWrite() + " ");
        System.out.println(" - Lectura: " + infoF.canRead() + " ");
        System.out.println(" - Ejecucion: " + infoF.canExecute() + " ");
        System.out.println("Ruta: " + infoF.getAbsolutePath() + " ");
        System.out.println("Tamaño: " + infoF.length() + " ");
        //cal.setTimeInMillis(infoF.lastModified());
        //System.out.println("Fecha: " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    }
    /**
     * Get directory info
     * 
     * @param path 
     */
    public static void mostrarInfoDirectori(String path)
    {
        File infoD = new File(path);
        System.out.println("Nombre directorio: " + infoD.getName());
        System.out.println("Permisos: ");
        System.out.println(" - Escritura: " + infoD.canWrite() + " ");
        System.out.println(" - Lectura: " + infoD.canRead() + " ");
        System.out.println(" - Ejecucion: " + infoD.canExecute() + " ");
        System.out.println("Ruta: " + infoD.getAbsolutePath() + " ");
        System.out.println("Tamaño: " + infoD.length() + " ");
        //cal.setTimeInMillis(infoD.lastModified());
        //System.out.println("Fecha: " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    }
    /**
     * Delete dile
     * 
     * @param path 
     */
    public static void esborrarFitxer(String path)
    {
        File file_del = new File(path);
        file_del.delete();

       // closeMe(file_del);
    }
    /**
     * Delete directory
     * 
     * @param path 
     */
    public static void esborrarDirectori(String path)
    {
        File dir_del = new File(path);
        dir_del.delete();

        //closeMe(dir_del);
    }
    /**
     * Change file name
     * 
     * @param path
     * @param nom 
     */
    public static void canviarNom(String path, String nom)
    {
        File nom_file = new File(path);




    }
    /**
     * My try at a general method to close File classes
     * 
     * @param path 
     */
    public static void closeMe(Closeable path)
    {
        try
        {
            path.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not be closed");
        }
    }



    /**
     * Main method
     * 
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mostrarInfoFitcher("C:\\Users\\alumneM\\Desktop\\bitcoin.txt");
        mostrarInfoFitcher("C:\\Users\\alumneM\\Desktop\\bitcoin.docx");





    }    
}
```

**Problem**

1. Having all those File classes inside those methods makes me believe it is not efficient. There must be something else better and more professional.
2. Following the first problem I encounter myself with, What happens when the File class variable on each method is not being used? Does it consume resources? How can I close it?

   2.1 Following the second problem, I can simply use .close() method on those variables and I do not understand why.

**What I am looking for in this question?**

- Understand my mistakes and learn from them
- New tips for coding similar programs or dealing with files
- Suggestions is how to improve the way I code

**Notes**

- I added Javadoc to help understand the method and it's goal.

**Goal**

I want to make a Java program where I input a path to a file and I can apply those methods on it.

Comment: Instead of passing the path everywhere, maybe make a method that creates a `File` from the `path` and make the argument for every method `File` instead, so you aren't creating it everywhere.

Comment: That's something I though but not sure how to implement it. Could you provide me a quick example?

Comment: Yeah sure, give me a sec

Comment: You shouldn't actually be using the `File` class anyway. It's an old, badly written class. You should instead use `Path`, using the `Paths` class to create and `Files` to do file manipulation operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main or wherever you declare a new file you can do this to create the file and call the method:

```
    String path = "/example";
    File file = new File(path);
    esborrarDirectori(file);
```

If you make each method use File as an argument instead, for example one will look like this:

```
public static void esborrarDirectori(File file)
{
    file.delete();
}
```

You can also make your own method for creating a returning a File if you want to do other operations on it at the time like this:

```
public static File createFile(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    return file;
}
```

Which would be used by calling it with:

```
    String path = "/example";
    File file = createFile(path);
```

This does not have much of a purpose unless you plan on adding some other functionality to the createFile() method.

Generally, for good practice, you should not create a new `File` unless you are actually opening a new file.  If you are using the same `File` multiple times, you should create it once, and send it to the methods it needs to be used.